# Какой метод авторизации ВК нужно использовать в моем случае?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, oauth2

Зачем мне авторизация? В моем JS-приложении нужно реализовать поиск групп. Для поиска групп нужен access_token.

Я пытался получить access_token используя oauth, но на сколько я понял, мне нельзя использовать oauth, т.к. у меня веб-приложение, а не десктопное/мобильное.

OpenAPI вообще не предоставляет возможности получить access_token.

Что в итоге мне использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае, все таки, подходит oauth.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI как раз то, что вам нужно. Токен сохраняется где-то внутри, и вам он в явном виде не требуется. Вот [пример](https://new.vk.com/dev/openapi) авторизации пользователя. После успешно авторизации с запросом прав "groups", можете вызывать методы API: `VK.Api.call('groups.search', {q: 'Music' ...`

Comment: Ну да, Вы правы, наверное openapi проще, и этим лучше. Oauth напрямую лучше если надо в перспективе прикрутить все подряд: и вконтакт, и твиттер с фейсбуком и прочее

Comment: Из документации к OpenAPI `groups - Доступ к группам пользователя.`. А мне нужен доступ к поиску глобальному поиску групп. Из за этого я и сделал вывод, что мне этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: так что в итоге – вы попробовали, всё получилось? Вопрос закрыт или что-то уточнить?